# Not able to change video data in standout library

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I am using standout library and this code in createAndAttachView method in 'SimpleWindow' class

```
 Removed for security purpose
```

But after choosing a video, toast is show with selected video path but i am not able to change video in videoView. Can you tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: are you getting any crash?

Comment: No, There is no error in Log cat.

Comment: How you are accessing `SimpleWindow` in `StandOutExampleActivity` ?

Comment: You can see i am opening file chooser by refering standOutExampleActivity  StandOutExampleActivity.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, DEFAULT_ID);
             So when i choose file i returns to onactivity result so toast will show, But i am not able to change video data

Comment: you will change VideoView url from only if you access `localVideoView` object in `onActivityResult` which is currently in `SimpleWindow`

Comment: Ok i changed localVideoView visibility to default, and accessing this object by this SimpleWindow s1=new SimpleWindow();
        s1.localVideoView.setVideoPath(path);  Now i getting this error:------Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/video/media/21 }} to activity {wei.mark.example/wei.mark.example.StandOutExampleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: :just for testing make `localVideoView` public static then try to access it as `SimpleWindow.localVideoView` instead of by create `SimpleWindow` class Object

Comment: Thanks Now i am able to change video data, But when i choose video second time i got this exception 'android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?'

Comment: How can i accept your answer?